# File Missing Error on Apple Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Hi I am configuring APNS to my app with help of Urban Airship. I successfully on notification on my app but can't set for Urban Airship. My App in urban airship show me 0 device registered, and i am getting many warning on Airship files.
[image]

Above image is screen shot of warning. I know i am doing silly mistake but don't know where. Also my Device token is not registered and i am not getting any device token. Kindly help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all Urban Airship files from project and add them again with "copy files" option.